# Adding additional exception information with Wrap Handler

Tags: exception, enterprise-library

Enterprise Library 5.0 Exception Handling includes the Wrap Handler. This wraps an exception in another exception and throws the wrapper exception.

I would like to add additional information to my wrapper exception, such as some information about the parameters and settings that were in effect when the error occurred.  This would be handy for troubleshooting (since this wrapper exception will be caught and logged by a higher-level handler).

I was using the following code:

```
ExceptionManager em = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ExceptionManager>();
em.Process(() => { DoSomething(); }, "WrapPolicy");
```

The result of this is an exception that gets wrapped in my custom exception and thrown.  This is clean and easy, but since my code never sees the wrapper exception instance, I can't augment it with additional information.

Other than wrapping the action in a traditional Try...Catch and executing the HandleException method manually, is there a way to inject additional information into the wrapper exception instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of additional information you want to add but if you want to maintain the elegance of the Process method then you could create a custom WrapHandler that adds the appropriate information to the wrapper exception.  A good candidate would be to add the additional information to the Exception.Data IDictionary.

If you are looking for method arguments then probably the only way to do it would be by creating your own "context", setting values in there, and extracting them from the context to add to the wrapping exception.

Another more elegant approach would be to use Policy Injection.  Call handlers have access to the method parameters as well as the exception thrown.  You could modify the existing ExceptionCallHandler to add your information to the original or new exception.  If you add the context information to the original exception then that information would be processed by the Exception Policy (which could include logging).

Comment: Hmm.  The issue I have with that is how the custom WrapHandler would have access to that information I want to include.  Say that the method in which the exception is being handled has some meaningful parameters that I want to associate with the exception.  How does the handler, which is invoked indirectly and several layers of code away, have access to those?

Comment: (having read your modified answer)  Thank you.  That's an approach I hadn't considered!

Answer (score 0):

You can supply an exception message when configuring the wrap handler.

```
    var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

    builder.ConfigureExceptionHandling()
               .GivenPolicyWithName("MyPolicy")
               .ForExceptionType<NullReferenceException>()
                 .WrapWith<InvalidOperationException>()
                   .UsingMessage(messageBasedOnSomeRuntimeInfo)
                 .ThenNotifyRethrow();

    var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
    builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);
    EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current 
          = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```

Comment: That's true, and it's convenient.  But what I need to add is *run time* information, about the conditions in place when the error  occurred.  I don't have that at configuration time.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Sure. Instead of extrenal config, use programmatic - via fluent API. See code sample in my revised answer.

Comment: Thank you, but what I meant by "run time" was "at the time the exception occurred".  So setting the message ahead of time can't reflect that.  But, thank you for your answer!

Comment: You don't have to set it ahead of time. This could be a calculated value.